# config/routes.rb and config/database.yml permission issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, terminal

I'm working with ruby on rails through terminal on a mac. Every time I try to gain access to these, including every file I've created through the ruby on rails guide I keep seeing

`Stephen-Troschs-MacBook-Pro:blog stephentrosch$ config/routes.rb`"

```
-bash: config/routes.rb: Permission denied'

Stephen-Troschs-MacBook-Pro:myapp stephentrosch$ app/views/home/index.html.erb
```

`-bash: app/views/home/index.html.erb: Permission denied'`

How would I gain the correct permissions?

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a filename by itself as a command, the OS attempts to *execute* it (run it as a program).

Those files are not meant to be executable (and wouldn't do anything if you did try to execute them), so they don't have that permission set.

You probably want to *read* them, for example by opening them in a text editor:

```
$ vi config.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the text editor of your choice to open those files. Like `vi config/routes.rb`
or any other editor as per your preference. You can also use any editors likes sublime, aptana which gives better flexibility to write code for beginners.